# Use SBT task result as a setting

Tags: scala, sbt

I'm writing an SBT plugin that plugin that interrogates project dependencies and I want to extend it to interrogate plugins. It gets dependencies at start-up by overriding `onload` [as described here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.12.4/docs/faq.html#how-can-i-take-action-when-the-project-is-loaded-or-unloaded) and I build a `State => State` function by passing in values from `libraryDependencies.value`.

To get hold of plugins it seems the only way is via the `discoveredSbtPlugins` **task**, therefore I can't call it in my `onload` override because `onload` is a setting.

So how can I get the result of `discoveredSbtPlugins.value` into my override of `onload`?

Comment: not sure this is the best approach (hence a comment and not an answer) but why not define a task `myOnLoad` that will depend on the `onLoad` setting and return it's result after you've modified it, and also, override all the tasks depending on `onLoad` to depend on `myOnLoad` instead?